# Want to use @Value (reading the properties from property file) in UIMA framework

Tags: spring, uima

I have a property file like myProperties.properties. I want to read one property like MAX_YEARS using spring annotation @value as like below in **UIMA JCasAnnotator_ImplBase extending class.**
**private @Value("${REQUIRED_COLUMNS}") String requiredColumns;**

Or any alternatives for reading properties from property file in UIMA framework.
Thanks in advance.
Narasimha.

Comment: I'd start from [this](https://uima.apache.org/uimafit.html): _uimafit-spring is an experimental module serving as a proof-of-concept for the integration of UIMA with the Spring Framework. It is currently not considered finished and uses invasive reflection in order to patch the UIMA framework such that it passes all components created by UIMA through Spring to provide for the wiring of Spring context dependencies. This module is made available for the adventurous but currently not considered stable, finished, or even a proper part of the package. E.g. it is not included in the binary distribu_

Answer (score 1):

UIMA does not support value injection via Java annotations (from Spring or any other DI frameworks) at this time. It does support [External Configuration Parameter Overrides](http://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.6.0/references.html#ugr.ref.xml.component_descriptor.aes.external_configuration_parameter_overrides), though.

uimaFIT offers annotations like [@ConfigurationParameter](http://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-current/tools.uimafit.book.html#ugr.tools.uimafit.configurationparameters) to inject UIMA parameters into fields. These parameter values can come from descriptors automatically generated by uimaFIT using reflection, or they can come from pre-built XML descriptors.

When using pre-built XML descriptors, it should be possible to employ the External Configuration Parameter Overrides mechanism in conjunction with uimaFIT - but I am not sure if this has already been tried by anybody.

It may even be possible to employ the External Configuration Parameter Overrides mechanism with the descriptors internally generated by uimaFIT.

*Disclosure: I am a developer on the UIMA project, focussing on uimaFIT.*